# How to make dragger of SplitLayoutPanel blink?

Tags: gwt

So, I have a SplitLayoutPanel, and need a blinked dragger. Is there any possibility to achive it? With CSS, of hardcode, whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** - Purely css effects would be cpu intensive and hence I would go for a gif based solution.

### Problem

The split layout panel uses two images to provide for [horizontal](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/theme/clean/public/gwt/clean/images/thumb_horz.png) and [vertical](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/theme/clean/public/gwt/clean/images/thumb_vertical.png) splitter. These are png images and cannot be animated (blinking effect).

### Solution

You can get blinking effect by using animated gif images.

You need to find a replacement "gif" image for both these which **blinks**. Then override the basic gwt styles and ensure you have **`!important`** suffixed to the styles that are overriden.

```
.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger {
  background: #e7e7e7 url(images/thumb_vertical_blinking.gif) center center no-repeat !important;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger {
  background: #e7e7e7 url(images/thumb_horz_blinking.gif) center center no-repeat !important;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,There is a possibility to achieve that by overriding  the default styles

```
.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger { horizontal dragger }
.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger { vertical dragger }


.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger {
       // your set of styles while dragging 
} 

.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger {
       // your set of styles while dragging 
}
```